# BNF: Swapping non-terminals place in the grammar rules effect on production

Tags: recursion, grammar, bnf

I have spent all of yesterday and 7x hours today trying to find a definitive answer to a question in an assignment. I have watched hours of lectures on BNF and EBNF but none have addressed my question. I have learned loads though :)

I hope somebody can point the way:

Given this Grammar

```
G = {N, T, S, P} 
T = {a, b, c, - , ×} 
N = {<goal>, <expr>, <term>, <factor>} 
S = <goal> 
P = 
<goal> ::= <expr> 
<expr> ::= <term> | <expr> - <term> 
<term> ::= <factor> | <term> × <factor> 
<factor> ::= a|b|c
```

and then change the rules to:

```
<goal> ::= <expr>
<expr> ::= <term> | <term> - <expr> 
<term> ::= <factor> | <factor> × <term>
<factor> ::= a|b|c
```

What effect does it have on the production?

All I can see is it changes the `LHS` recursion to `RHS` recursion. I'd really like to know what I'm missing.

Other questions in the assignment changed the order of the rules which I answered: Rules that are lower in the cascade of productions have higher precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with the lecturer I confirmed the only difference is: it changes the `LHS` recursion to `RHS` recursion.